# Changing the height of ConstraintLayout from wrap-content to 0dp changes height of children

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

Basically, I have a ConstraintLayout as a root and then 2 ConstraintLayouts as children, aligned vertically (with wrap-content as their height) and a final third one, to fill all remaining space (0dp height, all constraints are set). However, this third ConstraintLayout, first had wrap-content as its height and when I changed the height to 0dp, all of the Views within the third layout looked like they have no height (they have wrap-content as their height, this does not change). When I manually enter a height e.g. '30dp' as a View's height, it works, but wrap-content for a Views's height does not work. Also, setting a constraint i.e. for Bottom lifts the view up. Does anyone know what's going on?

[This](https://gyazo.com/a11c5fa030d4118fdf0f21ffcc886d6e) is the behaviour I am getting.

> == ConstraintLayout (root)
>
> == ConstraintLayout (wrap-content)
>
> == ConstraintLayout (wrap-content)
>
> == ConstraintLayout (height and width 0dp, all constraints set, fill remaining space)
>
> === View (0dp as width and wrap_content as height, however, no height is shown (mainly ImageView and EditTexts)).

See this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pI6U3.png), the red area is the ConstraintLayout I'm having problems with and the View within the layout are yellow colored.

This is my whole Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" android:id="@+id/constraintLayout28" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_team" android:id="@+id/imageView17" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />
        <AutoCompleteTextView android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="8dp" app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/cL1" app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView17"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:padding="4dp" android:background="@drawable/edittext"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:hint="Opdrachtgever*" />
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cL1"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp" app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView17" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">
            <AutoCompleteTextView android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/cL2" android:padding="4dp" android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginRight="4dp" android:hint="Voornaam" />
            <AutoCompleteTextView android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/cL3"
                android:padding="4dp" android:background="@drawable/edittext" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:hint="Achternaam" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout28"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" android:background="@color/dividerColor"
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout29" android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout29"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" android:id="@+id/constraintLayout30"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_location" android:id="@+id/imageView19" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView19" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp" app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="8dp" android:weightSum="1"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">
            <AutoCompleteTextView android:layout_width="0dp" android:hint="Straat" android:id="@+id/cL4"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="4dp" android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                android:layout_weight="0.8" android:layout_marginRight="4dp" />
            <EditText android:layout_width="0dp" android:hint="#" android:id="@+id/cL4Number"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="4dp" android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                android:layout_weight="0.2" android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <EditText android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/cL5"
            android:hint="Stad" android:padding="4dp" android:background="@drawable/edittext" android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp" app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView19" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout30"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" android:background="@color/dividerColor"
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout31" android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout31" android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cL6"
        android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="0dp">


        <ImageView android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="0dp" app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_description"
            android:id="@+id/imageView20" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
        <EditText android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/cL7"
            android:hint="Referentie nummer"  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" android:layout_marginRight="8dp" app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView20" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" android:padding="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext" />
        <AutoCompleteTextView android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/cL8"
            android:hint="Project" android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cL7"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView20" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp" app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" android:padding="4dp" android:background="@drawable/edittext" />
        <EditText android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="0dp" android:id="@+id/cL9"
            android:hint="Omschrijving" android:layout_marginRight="8dp" app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView20" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" android:padding="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cL8"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <ImageView android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bt_cL6" android:id="@+id/cL6"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post complete layout?

Comment: @AskQ I updated the post.

Comment: You have problem with CL below CL with id constraintLayout31. Its' heght is the problem right?

Comment: @AskQ I have a problem with the layout and its contents. The CL itself is sized good, all fields are correct and are applied correctly, however, all of its children views do not display any form of height (as depicted in the image in my original post), even though they have wrap-content as their height.

Comment: Yes it because its 0dp. Check the xml I posted!

Comment: Use https://www.diffnow.com/ to get the changes by comparing 2 xmls

Answer (score 1):

Copy this bellow code in your layout file.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout28"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView17"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"/>

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/cL1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:hint="Opdrachtgever*"
        android:padding="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView17"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView17"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cL1">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/cL2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Voornaam"
            android:padding="4dp"/>

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/cL3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Achternaam"
            android:padding="4dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout29"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout28">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout30"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout29"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout32">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView19"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView19"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/cL4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:hint="Straat"
            android:padding="4dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/cL4Number"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:hint="#"
            android:padding="4dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/cL5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:hint="Stad"
        android:padding="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView19"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout2"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout32"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout30"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cL6"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0">

    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView20"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/cL7"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
         app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
       />


     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/cL7"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Reference number"
         app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView20"
         app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
         />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
         android:id="@+id/cL8"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:hint="Project"
         app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView20"
         app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cL7"
         app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cL9"/>

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/cL9"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Omschrijving"
         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView20"
         app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cL8"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cL6"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout32"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"/>
```

Comment: I pretty much have the same structure: I have updated my original post.

Comment: i have modify my layout, please check

Answer (score 0):

When you constrain CL between two layouts, it is scoped to stretch between those two layouts, at runtime. At design preview you can't see it stretched to that remaining space, since it's a CL. Also don't use CL for showing divider. Use view tag.

You can use **below** feature of android studio to CL which you want to fill up remaining space. What it does is it changes **layout_height** of that CL to some values calculated at design time. (for example: 275dp).

[image: fill content]

Layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout28"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView17"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_allahabad_bank" />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/cL1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_allahabad_bank"
            android:hint="Opdrachtgever*"
            android:padding="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView17"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView17"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cL1">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/cL2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_allahabad_bank"
                android:hint="Voornaam"
                android:padding="4dp" />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/cL3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_allahabad_bank"
                android:hint="Achternaam"
                android:padding="4dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout29"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout28">

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout30"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout29">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView19"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logout" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView19"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/cL4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_allahabad_bank"
                android:hint="Straat"
                android:padding="4dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/cL4Number"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_allahabad_bank"
                android:hint="#"
                android:padding="4dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/cL5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_allahabad_bank"
            android:hint="Stad"
            android:padding="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView19"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout2" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout31"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout30">

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="275dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cL6"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout31">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView20"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_bank" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/cL7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_allahabad_bank"
            android:hint="Referentie nummer"
            android:padding="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView20"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/cL8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_allahabad_bank"
            android:hint="Project"
            android:padding="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView20"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cL7" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/cL9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_allahabad_bank"
            android:hint="Omschrijving"
            android:padding="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView20"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cL8" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cL6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"


        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"


        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_allahabad_bank" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```